# how to delete string stored in a variable using strrep?

Tags: string, matlab

I am a new matlab user, Can i delete a string using strrep by storing the string in a variable and use it to delete?for example

```
C = textread('input.txt', '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
expr = '[^\n]*.Data [^\n]*';
fileread_info = regexp(filetext, expr, 'match')
for id=i:length(fileread_info)
C = strrep(C, 'fileread_info{i}', '');
end
```

but this deletes the word expr in file input.txt. how to delete the string contained in the variable expr?thanks!

Comment: You should not have quotes around fileread_info{i}. You should also check out regexprep.

Answer (score 0):

As @Navan already suggested:

1. You can use `regexprep`:

   `C = regexprep( C, expr, '' ); % will do the regular expression search + replace in one commnad`
2. You should unquote `'fileread_info{i}'`:

   `C = strrep(C, fileread_info{i}, '');`

Comment: this just removes the expression stored in expr, how do i remove the entire string in which the expression stored in expr occurs?ex if expr='[^\n]*.Data [^\n]*'; how do i delete the entire string 'hello.this=this.data' instead of just removing .data?

Comment: @learningMatlab it seems to work for me. You might want to try `expr = '[^\n]*\.Data[^\n]*\n'`